# I overstayed in Ukraine during Covid. What does this stamp mean and will it affect getting a Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen-visas, overstaying, passport-stamps, ukraine

I was in Ukraine during Covid 19 and I overstayed because of that. When I was at the Lviv airport, I explained my situation to the officers. I did not pay any penalty. I got this stamp. What does it mean? And will it affect me if I want to apply for a Schengen visa?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a regular exit stamp.

Answer (score 18):

It means you left Ukraine from the Lviv airport on April 24th, 2021. (ЛЬВІВ is Ukrainian for "LVIV," all caps.) The numbers identify the stamp or the officer.  If they identify the stamp, there should be a log that allows authorities to determine which officer was using the stamp at the time of your departure.

The stamp does not say one way or the other whether any information was recorded about your overstay in connection with your departure.

Comment: i just worried because other departure stamps from ukraine i got with red color , just this one with black color

Comment: @احمدمحمد Did those stamps have the same design?  If not, the change in ink color is imost likely because Ukraine has adopted this design and with it a change in ink color.  The design is substantially similar to that of the Schengen area, and non-Schengen countries have also adopted similar designs, so it would not be particularly surprising if Ukraine has done so even though it has not joined the Schengen area.

Comment: the old ones with the red color have slightly different design , i just want to be sure before applying to a shengen , i have no clue how to check that overstayed infos stored in their database

Comment: @احمدمحمد If the application asks whether you ever overstayed (which I believe is not the case for Schengen applications, though it is the case for some other countries), you should reply yes and explain the circumstances. As far as I know Ukraine does not share such information with members of the Schengen Area, and the stamp is a generic exit stamp (though the "exit" arrow is is bit smudged), but consular officials can easily read stamps and dates and make their own calculations if they want to, so it's better to admit the overstay rather than deny it and then be caught red-handed.

Answer (score 6):

> And will it affect me if I want to apply for a Schengen visa?

The Schengen visa application form doesn't ask about prior overstays and Ukraine doesn't share immigration information with Schengen countries, so the answer is **no**, you would not be affected in the slightest.